# Instagram api media/search stop work after 1st June 2016

Tags: instagram-api

Since 2 days (1 June 2016), endpoint (media/search) result: Oops, an error occurred.

https://api.instagram.com/v1/media/search?lat=48.858844&lng=2.294351&access_token=[MY ACCESS TOKEN]

What has gone wrong?

Answer (score 5):

From the Instagram website:

> Instagram Platform and documentation update. Apps created on or after Nov 17, 2015 will start in Sandbox Mode and function on newly updated API rate-limits and behaviors. Prior to going Live, and being able to be used by people other than the developers of the app, these apps will have to go through a new review process. Please read the API documentation or the Change Log for more details.
>
> Any app created before Nov 17, 2015 will continue to function until June 1, 2016. On that date, the app will automatically be moved to Sandbox Mode if it wasn't approved through the review process. The previous version of our documentation is still available here.

You will need to go through the app review process again to receive a new API Key, which involves providing a description of the api permissions you need and demonstrating how those permissions are used via a submitted video.

More details on http://instagram.com/developer

Answer (score 2):

Instagram updated there api process:  http://instagram.com/developer

Here is the process to get access:
Step 1: First login to your instagram account
Step 2:  Open : https://www.instagram.com/developer/register/ OR you can click open from menu 'Sandbox Invites'.
Fill - up and submit the form. 
Step 3: Open https://www.instagram.com/developer/clients/register/ Or Click 'Manage Clients' -> 'Register a New Client'
Fill Up Form.
Setp 4: You will possible get 
CLIENT INFO like, CLIENT ID, CLIENT SECRET
Using your Clinet_ID & Redirect URl you can get you new access token

https://www.instagram.com/oauth/authorize?client_id=CLIENT_ID&redirect_uri=WEB_REDIRECT_URL&response_type=token&scope=basic+public_content

Your will get your access_token in url = access_token=[ACCESS_KEY].

For exmaple if you want to get image with HASHTAG your url will be below.

```
$url = 'https://api.instagram.com/v1/tags/'.$tag.'/media/recent?client_id='.$client_id.'&access_token='.$access_token;
```

Comment: I've tried these steps . I continue with the same error . The error only happens in this endpoint : media / search .

Comment: @MauricioFerreira some endpoint will not work before approval